# Show that Legendre polynomial satisfies $\int P_n(x)dx=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}[P_{n+1}(x)-P_{n-1}(x)]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, legendre-polynomials

Show that Legendre polynomial satisfies $$\int P_n(x)dx=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}[P_{n+1}(x)-P_{n-1}(x)]$$

Adding $$nP_n(x)=xP_n'(x)-P'_{n-1}(x)$$ and $$P'_{n+1}(x)=xP_n'(x)+(n+1)P_n(x)~,$$ we get

$$P_{n+1}'(x)+P_{n-1}'(x)=2xP_n'(x)+P_n(x)$$

I am supposed to integrate this and get the result, but that's not working. Please help!

Comment: It is easy from the generating function $f(x,t)=(1-2xt+t^2)^{-1/2}= \sum_n P_n(x) t^n$,  $t\partial_t f(x,t)+x \partial f(x,t)=...$. The orthogonality follows from $\int_{-1}^1 f(x,t)f(x,u)dx = g(tu)$

Comment: You have got a *sum* of derivatives, and you want to get a *subtraction*... don't add, subtract.

Comment: @vonbrand That worked! Thank you :)

Comment: Please add an answer to your question solving the problem (and wait a few days, if nothing better shows up, accept it).